# Copying Array of Char * Corrupts Data

Tags: c, pointers, copy, char, corruption

I'm relatively new to C in general and I'm having a problem with some code. It's pretty simple code: The objective of the code is to copy a given array of char pointers, or char **source, in other words, to a given char **destination.

The issue I'm having is that sometimes (usually when I have more than 2 strings in source) the first element gets completely corrupted and when I end up printing out destination, it will print out something like ";@?" for the first element, with the other elements printing fine.

The code that performs the copying is:

```
void CopyArrayOfStrings(char **source, int numStrings)
{
   char **destination = malloc(numStrings);

    for (int i = 0; i < numStrings; i++)
    {
        destination[i] = malloc(strlen(source[i] + 1);
        strcpy(destination[i], source[i]);
    }
}
```

Note that I left out the code that checks if the result of malloc is NULL.

Comment: Why not use strdup() to duplicate the strings?

Comment: I must have missed the fact that strdup existed, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your allocation of `destination` as :

```
char **destination = malloc(numStrings*(sizeof(char*)));
```

to allocate number of `char *` pointers to hold strings.

Also verify you are appropriately passing `char **` as source array of strings.

Comment: Seems to working fine with this one minor change, thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong.

```
void CopyArrayOfStrings(char **source, int numStrings)
{
   char **destination = malloc(numStrings * sizeof(char *));

    for (int i = 0; i < numStrings; i++)
    {
        destination[i] = malloc(strlen(source[i]) + 1);
        strcpy(destination[i], source[i]);
        //alternatively you can use strdup() as suggested by @Christoffer
    }
}
```

This will give you storage space for `numStrings` arrays. Each element of which, will point to a null-terminated string.